# Credit default swap price quote conversion

Tags: credit-derivatives

How to convert cds prices quoted in PTS or PRICE to BPS? Eg. If CDS price quoted as 37 PTS then what is the equivalent in BPS and how to calculate  that?

Comment: This question is very much a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You convert between the upfront fee and the "market standard quote" annual spread using the CDS standard model. https://www.cdsmodel.com/cdsmodel/ the numbers are affected by your recovery assumption and (a little) by the risk-free interest rates.